# "Page With Redirect" issue for index document

Tags: seo, google-search-console, 302-redirect

I use the [Pelican](https://getpelican.com/) static site generator with [Attila](https://github.com/arulrajnet/attila) which automatically creates a page for each of my site's categories (`/categories.html`).

The default configuration for Attila created category URLs - and canonicals, for each category without a trailing slash.

e.g.

```bash
https://example.com/category/coins
```

...vs.

```bash
https://example.com/category/coins/
```

This led to a **Page Redirect** issue:

```html
Search Console has identified that your site is affected by 1 Page indexing issue(s). The following issues were found on your site.

Top Issues

Page with redirect
We recommend that you fix these issues when possible to enable the best experience and coverage in Google Search.
```

I edited my site such that the **Canonical** uses the full URL.  If, for example, you go to

```bash
https://example.com/category/coins
```

The browser redirects to

```bash
https://example.com/category/coins/
```

And the page source includes:

```html
<link href="https://example.com/category/coins/index.html" rel="canonical" />
```

In addition, I updated all my sitemaps to point to the full URL (trailing with index.html)    and all internal links point to the full URL.

I then clicked **Validate Fix** on the Google Search Console and the validation failed.

I'm concerned that the **coins** path (without trailing slash) returns a **302** and not **301** response.

I really don't care if Google indexes that page, but I took a significant hit on impressions after Google alerted me to the **Page with Redirect** issue.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to validate this **Page with redirect** issue?

Comment: Please show us how you have done the redirection.

Comment: @RohitGupta - Thank you.  I use Amazon S3 to host my website.  They redirect for me using via an index document.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/IndexDocumentSupport.html

Comment: What HTTP status code is the URL generating a 301 or 302?

Comment: @HunterNelson - The URL generates a 302

Comment: A 302 is a temporary redirect, if you want the redirect to be permanent use a 301.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to successfully "validate/fix" the "Page redirect" issue is to prevent the redirect that appends the trailing slash. This would be relatively trivial to resolve on something like Apache/`.htaccess`, but I don't believe this is possible with Amazon S3.

The 302 (temporary) redirect is also problematic (any redirect would be problematic), but the 302 is not cached by the client, so users would be repeatedly redirected via the server every time they click on a link (even the same link). Which is what Google is warning about.

The alternative is to change your URLs throughout and use the "canonical" URL *with* the trailing slash. (And ignore the "Page redirect" warning in GSC.) You should not be using the URL with `index.html` (the index document). Including `index.html` in the visible URL is just not necessary and clutters the URL.

(Although if you have already exposed `index.html` then it may be more work to try and remove it. Although I believe [Amazon S3 does support redirects](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/how-to-page-redirect.html).)

Comment: Excellent response, especially the part about using the trailing slash in the canonical.  I asked StackExchange how to do a 301 redirect here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75497515/how-do-i-301-redirect-a-single-page-on-my-cloudfront-s3-hosted-web-page

Comment: Can I hire you to help me troublehoot?

Answer (score 1):

Many of the errors in the pages report in Google Search Console aren't things that need to be validated or can be validated fully.  Page with redirect being one of them.  If a URL was previously indexed and you add a 301 redirect to the URL it will stay in this page with a redirect report.  For instance, if you have a `domain.com/sample-blog-post` but later decide you want to move all your blog posts to a subdirectory, such as `/blog`, then your `domain.com/blog/sample-blog-post` will now be indexed, but `domain.com/sample-blog-post` will show up in the page with redirect report.  This is perfectly harmless and to be expected.

It takes some time for search engines to crawl the URLs, understand the redirect relationships and restore traffic flow.  I suggest requesting manual indexing on both the previous URL and the new canonical destination URL to speed up the process.

[Video showing how to request manual indexing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mROpqtnpvXE)

Comment: Rather than posting a video, it would be better if you posted screenshots,  Links can disappear, which would make your answer useless in the future.

Comment: Thank you @HunterNelson.  Google sent me a message on January 15th: "To the owner of https://john.soban.ski/: Search Console has identified that your site is affected by 1 Page indexing issue(s). The following issues were found on your site. Top Issues Page with redirect."  The next day my impressions TANKED by 99% and have not returned.  I suspect the two things relate to each other.  If I delete the entire "categories" folder will that at least validate the fix?  I know this will move to a "page not found" error, but I want to get rid of the redirect error ASAP.

Comment: It sounds like you are in a situation where you need to do a redirect.  Having a redirect appear in the report is unavoidable, so to that extent, I think your question has been answered. What you are really trying to get at is how to make sure your canonicals and redirects are all set up properly so you can recover your traffic which probably crosses the line into consulting.  My thought based on the info you have provided above, is that you need to have a canonical with the 'https://example.com/category/coins/', notice the index.html is omitted, and redirects pointing to it.

Comment: Thanks @HunterNelson I appreciate it.  I originally had the canonical as "coins with no trailing slash."  Unfortunately, this lead to a 302 redirect to "coins with a trailing slash" and Google search complained about the redirect.  I decided to delete the pages entirely, hopefully a 404 will drop the troublesome pages out of the index.  I will post a reply if that fixes things.

Comment: You need 301 redirects, not 302.

Comment: Thanks @HunterNelson - I tried to get Cloudfront/S3 to redirect w/ a 301 and I failed miserably.   I opened a question on StackExchange https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75497515/how-do-i-301-redirect-a-single-page-on-my-cloudfront-s3-hosted-web-page that describes my failure and asks for help